# Angular 8.2 Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-upgrade

I´m upgrading a legacy project from angular 7.2 to 8.2 and after it, when I execute ng serve it shows this error:

*ERROR in app/service/broadcast.service.ts:21:5 - error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscriber': syncErrorValue, syncErrorThrown, syncErrorThrowable, isStopped, and 8 more.*

*21     return this.subscriber.subscribe(generator);*

**broadcast.service.ts**

```
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscriber} from 'rxjs';
import {BroadcastObject} from '../utils/interfaces/OnBroadcast.interface';

/**
 * BroadcastService: Simple service to broadcast object-like message between components
 */
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BroadcastService {
  public subscriber:EventEmitter<any>;
  constructor() {
    this.subscriber = new EventEmitter();
  }
  broadcast(name:string, data: any) {
    this.subscriber.emit({name, data});
  }
  subscribe(generator:Function):Subscriber<BroadcastObject> {
    return this.subscriber.subscribe(generator);
  }
}
```

**OnBroadcast.interface.ts**

```
export interface BroadcastObject {
 name:string;
 data:any;
}
export interface OnBroadcast {
 onBroadcast(data:BroadcastObject):any;
}
```

After googling I´ve tried by removing *.subscribe(generator)* part, but then console arrows this error:

*ERROR in app/service/broadcast.service.ts:21:5 - error TS2740: Type 'EventEmitter' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscriber': syncErrorValue, syncErrorThrown, syncErrorThrowable, destination, and 10 more.*

*21     return this.subscriber;*

Do you know how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typings don't look quite correct here. There are several possible things you could do:

1. Change your `subscribe` method to return an rxjs `Subscription`:

```js
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
...
subscribe(generator: Function): Subscription {
  return this.subscriber.subscribe(generator);
}
```

2. Refactor your `subscribe` method to just return the observable, and rely on the caller to subscribe:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
...
getObservable(): Observable<BroadcastObject> {
  return this.subscriber;
}
...
// in calling code:
broadcastService.getObservable().subscribe(value => {
  // ...
});
```

The variable you have named `subscriber` is an Angular [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) (which is basically a wrapper around an rxjs [`Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject)): this means it acts like a data channel where you can send data into it using the `emit` method, and listen for data with the `subscribe` method. This `subscribe` method returns a [`Subscription`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription) which can be used to cancel the subscription via the `unsubscribe` method.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This code isnt mine :{... If I apply your point 1), I´m getting a bunch of new errors like this one:  *Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Subscriber<BroadcastObject>'.

29     this.sub = this.broadcaster.subscribe(info => {*

Comment: The second approach is not an option because broadcastService.subscribe method is called in more than 50 files. Do you know why this code is working in Angular 7.2 and not in Angular 8.2?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would work in an earlier version of Angular, perhaps the `subscribe` is typed as `any` in that version. It seems like you will need to update the types from `Subscriber<BroadcastObject>` to `Subscription` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I´ve changed Subscriber<BroadcastObject> to Subscription and it works ;)